# Zend 2 default route

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I'm having troubles with default routing in ZF2:

```
 'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'hostbill-api' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/api/hostbill',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'service' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'call'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Hostbill\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Api',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'hostbill-api-service' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '[/:service[/:call]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'service' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'call'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'hostbill-api-hook' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/hook[/:action]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Hostbill\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Hook',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

What I want to do, it's when I call **URL/api/hostbill/hook/non_existent_action** url, the *default* action it's called.

Actually, if I call an existent action, the routing work, but if I use a non existent hook action, the default isn't called and a 404 is fired.

Any help apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in your controller :

```
/**
 * Create an HTTP view model representing a "not found" page
 *
 * @param  HttpResponse $response
 * @return ViewModel
 */
protected function createHttpNotFoundModel(HttpResponse $response)
{
    return $this->indexAction();//or whatever that is your default action is
}
```

or this one :

```
/**
 * Action called if matched action does not exist
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function notFoundAction()
{
    return $this->indexAction();//or whatever that is your default action is
}
```

Comment: nice ! love this way to do this so much instead of using events